# Spying on Wi-Fi-connected device from laptop

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wireshark, hotspot, connection-sharing

I want to capture (and possibly modify) packets from a WiFi-connected device using my MacBook Pro and I am trying to figure out the most straightforward way of doing so. **I have solved the problem** (multiple times before). I just want to figure out how to do this with minimum effort since the need arises from time to time and I find myself spending too much time on this issue, and it tends to involve too much hardware.

So far I've tried:

- Using the internet connection sharing in OSX. **Failed**: It appears that I cannot share a Wi-Fi connection over a Wi-Fi connection (looks to me like an artificial limitation in OSX, maybe it is possible to override this somehow?). If I were to find a way of doing this, it would be my preferred approach.
- Bootcamping to Win10 to do the same ([`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`](https://www.maketecheasier.com/windows-10-wifi-hotspot/) method). **Failed**: The device shows up, but the network does not work (never becomes properly "connected" to the internet). At one point I had it working except that DNS resolution did not work, but when I tried to manually set DNS it stopped working again. My impression is that the functionality is very unstable with little possibility of troubleshooting. Maybe there are some steps that the guides that [show up on Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22windows%2010%22%20create%20hotspot) fail to mention?
- Connecting the Mac to wired Ethernet and sharing over Wi-Fi. **Works**, but I no longer own a Thunderbolt display and I prefer an all-wireless solution. I could probably buy a Thunderbolt to Eternet adapter, but I'd rather not buy yet another piece of computer cable that I will almost never need (already got whole boxes of those in the basement)
- Installing a second Wi-Fi adapter (which I happen to already have in mentioned boxes). I tried this in OSX but it appears that there is no driver for it. If found links to some Hackintosh forums but I am not keen on installing unsigned drivers from dubious sources (especially for which there is no source code). And even if I found a working adapter, I am not sure if OSX would allow it anyway as I found no info on the subject. I also tried in Windows and it worked more or less the same as using only the built-in adapter (i.e. network shows and I can authenticate, but no Internet).

What I am looking for then is primarily a way of convincing OSX to create a wireless hotspot even if I have no wired connection (similar to what Windows does), or failing that a way of doing the same in a robust way in Windows 10 (i.e. creating a network that actually *works*).

Comment: so who are you spying on/stealing from ?

Comment: In this case a badly programmed web radio

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not me, i was just curious about the question. Let's set that back to zero =)